# node.js debugging with node-inspector and forever.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever, node-inspector

I am unable to debug node.js server when using forever.js. Is it not possible?

```
Exampel: forever start --debug server.js
```

1) Starts the server.js ok, but I am unable to debug with node-inspector.

2) forever.js as: `forever start server.js`
Does not re-start the server - this is the core service of forever?

I am working on a mac.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 12):

> Starts the server.js ok, but I am unable to debug with node-inspector.

Forever does not support debug mode out of the box. You can get around it by asking forever to start a custom command:

```
$ forever -c 'node --debug' server.js
```

> Does not re-start the server - this is the core service of forever?

I assume you would like to restart the server after a change in source files. I am not very familiar with forever, but I would say you forgot to add `-w` option to the command line?

```
    -w, --watch      Watch for file changes
```

To debug a process and have it automatically restarted, run

```
$ forever -w -c 'node --debug' server.js
```

See also this node-inspector issue: [#196](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/196).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just note that on Windows you should replace the single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Also, `node --debug` has been deprecated. Use `node --inspect`.

Answer (score 2):

Complete instructions on Windows with Chrome

In first terminal run

```
forever -w -c "node --debug" server.js
```

In second terminal run

```
node-inspector
```

Navigate to localhost:8080

Answer (score -1):

### Debug using v8 in chrome

in terminal write:

```
node inspect server.js
```

navigate to `chrome://inspect`
go to remote target inspect